# Use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE in API resource laravel

Tags: php, laravel

when i want to return texts in api resource get the following response :

```
{"data":{"message":"\u۰۶۳۳\u۰۶۴۴\u۰۶۲۷\u۰۶۴۵ \u۰۶۲۸\u۰۶۳۱ \u۰۶۲a\u۰۶۴۸"},"status":۰}
```

this problem solved in `response()->json` when i add following code to response :

`return 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

like:

```
return response()->json(['message' => 'my utf8 text'], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

but in api resource i can't add this code to response

api resource code:

```
    public function toArray($request) {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'userId' => $this->user_id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'text' => $this->text,
            'isAccepted' => $this->is_accepted,
            'viewCount' => $this->view_count,
            'likeCount' => $this->like_count,
            'dislikeCount' => $this->dislike_count,
            'commentCount' => $this->comment_count,
            'createdAt' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime($this->created_at)),
        ];
    }

    public function with($request) {
        return [
          'status' => Status::SUCCESS
        ];
    }
```

how i can solve this problem ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to edit below function in "Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse.php"

```
public function __construct($data = null, $status = 200, $headers = [], $options = 0)
{
    $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'charset' => 'utf-8'];
    $options = JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE;
    $this->encodingOptions = $options;

    parent::__construct($data, $status, $headers);
}
```

Comment: I mean, one **can** edit library classes, but it's ultimately self-defeating because it mandates the same thing be done every time you `composer install` or `composer upgrade`. A better solution, I feel, would be to add code in the application that configures or overrides the library's behavior.

Comment: Agreed. This should not be an accepted answer ;)

Comment: Sad to see this is seemingly the only method that allows to override Json parameters globally, instead of having to create a new class and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `setEncodingOptions` when returning JSON from your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class MyController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $myJsonStructure = [
            'data' => '۶۲۷۶۴۸',
        ];
        // SET the bit flag in the encoding options
        // (default encoding options are:
        //  JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT = 15)
        $response = Response::json($myJsonStructure);
        return $response->setEncodingOptions(
            $response->getEncodingOptions() | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
        );
        // -OR- replace all encoding options with a set of my choosing
        return Response::json($myJsonStructure)
            ->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_HEX_AMP);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

another way is using `toJSON` function in your controller like this:

```
 return response((new YourResource($response))->toJSON(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but will be helpful for anyone having a similar issue of character encoding in the JSON response.

The JsonResource class has a `withResponse` method that can be used in the API Collection or Resource class to add the charsets or any other header.

Add the below method in your API Collection class, like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\Product;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class ProductCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }

    /**
     * Customize the outgoing response for the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Response
     * @return void
     */
    public function withResponse($request, $response)
    {   
        $response->header('Charset', 'utf-8');
        $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }

}
```

Comment: I want to note that when using single resources and collections together you must implement this for both: resource AND collection. Using something like `EventResource::collection($events->get())` does NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change json encode options by adding this:

```
class MeetupResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function jsonOptions()
    {
        return JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION;
    }
}
```

List of all flags can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
return response()->json(['data' => YourResource::collection($data)], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

This will return your data wrapped by a data[] .